# DIY power connection to ventilation unit

Tags: electrical, ventilation

I bought a ventilation unit that came with a bit more DYI required than anticipated since I'm a complete noob when it comes to electrical stuff.

I have a picture of the unit itself, the power connector inside and the part from the manual where it says how I should connect it. I've searched online for what this means, but I'm not able to put it together.

One part I can't figure out is if the min/max refers to serially connecting multiple units and the power I would be required to supply if I connect multiple units, or if it refers to if I want to run the unit with min/max speed (RPM).

From my searching I guess one part of it is that I can connect a power switch.

Can anyone with more experience please help me explain how I need to connect this to a power cable?

The unit: https://i.ibb.co/ZcSQ4DH/3.jpg 
The power connector inside: https://i.ibb.co/4gdPbwH/1.jpg 
The manual: https://i.ibb.co/Wk00B16/4.jpg

Comment: Max/min is that it has two speeds, if you want.  It requires a power(on/off) switch between the power line and the unit and a selector switch if you want to choose the two speeds.

Answer (score 1):

That is a good starter for diy.

- Connect the neutral to the N terminal
- If you want full speed connect the hot to terminal L2
- For slow speed connect the hot to the terminal L1

A 3 position selector switch can be used for off, on low, on high.

If you only want 1 speed use a standard switch and connect to the speed you want.

In the U.S. the neutral is usually white. In many other locations it is blue.

However, beware that this item is marked CE but not any of the real certifications (UL, ETL, etc.) and likely has no real certification or testing at all. Install at your own risk. This item is designed (or says it is designed) for ~ 230V. But the frequency is listed as 50/60, implying use in both US/Canada and elsewhere. In the US, that means *hot to hot*, not *hot to neutral*. A US installation hot to neutral will not work properly. A US installation hot to hot should work just fine, but depending on design there may be safety issues.

Comment: If you're not going to use punctuation, please at least use lists. Your posts are sometimes very hard to understand.

Comment: I didn't bother to answer, figuring someone else would catch the issues. I'll add a junk danger warning.

Comment: This is a 230-volt unit. Connecting neutral to N and hot to L1 or L2 will result in a 110/120 volt connection.